# Two identical formulas producing differing results

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table of items and a table of categories. Each item is saved with it co-ordinates, latitude (lat) and longitude (lon), to allow users to search geographically.

When I do a search for items, those which have exactly the same lat and lon as the user, show in one query but not the other.

One query simply selects all items within a category (2), within a range (<1).

```
SELECT *, c.name as category, c.category_id as CATid, 
( 3959 * acos( cos( radians(52.993252) ) 
* cos( radians( i.latitude ) ) 
* cos( radians( i.longitude ) - radians(-0.412470) ) 
+ sin( radians(52.993252) ) 
* sin( radians( i.latitude ) ) ) ) AS distance 
from items i 
join categories c on i.category=c.category_id 
where i.category=2 group by i.item_id 
HAVING distance < 1 
order by distance
```

The other query selects all the categories and counts the number of items within each category, within the specified geographic range (<1)

```
SELECT *, ( SELECT ( count( 3959 * acos( cos( radians(52.993252) ) 
* cos( radians( latitude ) ) 
* cos( radians( longitude ) 
- radians(-0.412470) ) 
+ sin( radians(52.993252) ) 
* sin( radians( latitude ) ) ) )) AS distance 
FROM items 
WHERE category = category_id 
HAVING distance < 2  ) AS howmanyCat,
( SELECT name FROM categories WHERE category_id = c.parent ) AS parname 
FROM categories c ORDER BY category_id, parent
```

Strangely, if you change the search parameter for distance to **2** on the second query it finds it!

Any ideas?

[Here is a fiddle to show what I mean](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b22a7/14)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second query is assigning the `count()` value as `distance`.

The first is assigning the arithmetic calculation as `distance`.

The first is doing what you want, and it is a clearer query.

EDIT:

I also note that the first query is aggregating by `item_id`.  The second is not doing an explicit aggregation in the outer query, but it is choosing all categories.  This is another difference between the versions.

Comment: but the first query produces one row - therefore if i mimic the query inside count() it should still return 1? this was the only way I could think to search on an alias but not show it as I can only have one field within the bigger alias - if that makes sense

Comment: Note that you have a GROUP BY in your first query but none in the second.  The HAVING clause operates on the data post grouping.

Comment: tried adding group by item_id same as first query - no change

Comment: @DarrenSweeney . . . The fundamental problem is that `distance` in the first query is some calculated distance between two things.  `distance` in the second formula is an integer produced by `count()`.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Damn!!! Yes, of course... I've been looking at this too long. Thank you